# Unable to find the WPF custom control using coded ui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate WPF application (WPF with 3rd party devexpress) using coded UI (VS 2012) in my local machine (Windows server 2008 R2).

I am facing issues while identifying controls under dynamically generated content of the window. I've Tried different hierarchical levels to hit the control,But i am 
still not able to hit the control.

Till some level I am getting the handle, but after I am not getting the handle.

My application is complex hierarchically structured with combining winforms and WPF.

I've Tried to use coded UI record and play feature to generate the UI Map and  used the same structure to identify the controls. It worked while debugging line by line but it's failing while running.

e.g. Below is one hierarchy,

List item

- Dashboard
- Dash_Grid
- LayoutManager
- LayoutGroup
- LayoutPanel -->Till this level I am able to get the handle and lower I am not able to hit the control
- Container
- Navtop
- Nav_Grid
- TileLayoutControl

  ........(all tiles)

This issue is not only with one page. I am having the same problem with all the pages.So this is blocking our automation.

Please can any one help me on this?

Comment: What is your devexpress version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this two possible solutions:

1. Use the devexpress extension for codedui to identify and locate dexExpress controls:

   > https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/coded-ui/
2. Dont replicate the elaborate hierarchy of your app when identifying controls but instead select the main controls in the hierarchy and use them to set your search properties. this is especially important for dynamically created content where the hierarchy is constantly changing. 
   in your example:

   ```
   var List_item = new WpfListItem(parent);

   List_item.SearchProperties.. = some search properties
   ```

   and than set your control's parent to that top list item and ignore the midlle   men:

   ```
   var  Container = new UITestControl(List_item);
   ```

   where UITestControl should be replaced with the controls actuall type.

Comment: Thanks for reply Barakcaf.                                                                     Under points 1,whatever extension they have mentioned is for windows form. I want devexpress extension for codedui for WPF controls not windows control.                                                                                             Under point 2,I have tried identifying control by selecting only main controls.But still it didnt work.                                                                                           Thanks,